# Square polygons that are covered by trees

Tags: arcgis-desktop, generalization

I would like to know if there is a way to square polygons?

I would like to calculate the total square meters of houses. I have extracted the buildings as well as tree coverage but I am unable to get a full total square meter of the house due to the tree coverage that covers the building.

I was thinking if there is a way that I can square out the building to try and accommodate the tree coverage?

Comment: I think you need to edit your question and include some images, it is unclear what you are asking?